# How to execute Batch by different user than submitting user?

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a request.

I have a class I extend a `RunBaseBatch` , I need to run the Batch process by a default and diferent user than submitting user.

For clarification, If the Batch is submitted/schedule by User **A** the *BatchJob* run by User **B**

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change batch job user identity (run as)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337580/change-batch-job-user-identity-run-as), it's for AX 2009, but should work for AX 2012, too.

Comment: Thanks @FH-Inway for your reply. I need to change the batch user executor, because with command runAs only allow the specific method to other user. Other methods called are executed by previous user. I would like to create the record in BatchJob History with _createdBy_ second user (in this case user B) . Complete batchJOB need to executed by user _B_